# PHPUnit test coverage API with mock

Tags: php, symfony, sonarqube, phpunit, code-coverage

I, I would like to cover a method that get an authentication form an API.

Here is my class:

```
class MyService
{
    private $api_token;
    private $uri_api;

    public function __construct(string $api_token, string $uri_api){
        $this->api_token = $api_token;
        $this->uri_api = $uri_api;
    }
    public function api_authentication(){
        $client = HttpClient::create();
        return $client->request('GET', $this->getUri_api().'salespoints/', [
            'auth_bearer' => $this->getApi_token()
        ]);
    }
}
```

And here is my test class:

```
class MyServiceTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function test_api_authentication(){
        $client = new HttpClient();

        $stub = $this->getMockBuilder(myService::class)
                    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                    ->disableOriginalClone()
                    ->disableArgumentCloning()
                    ->disallowMockingUnknownTypes()
                    ->getMock();
        $stub->method('api_authentication')->willReturn($client);
        $this->assertSame($client, $stub->api_authentication());
    }
}
```

I am using the doc of PHPUnit [here](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.3/test-doubles.html#stubs) (example 8.4).

The problem is that my test pass when I run phpunit but sonarQube tell me that it is not test coverage. I am new using phpunit so if you have any suggestions.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What are you testing, anyway? The whole test seems a bit pointless. Maybe you could clarify your intention.

Comment: Yes Philip I think what I want isn't possible to do. I wanted to test an api call but finally it's not incluted as a test coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after research, I think the method that I want to test is not possible to be covered. This is an API call and the coverage need to be done by the developper that written this code.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes that's right, you can coverage your code only. I think if you are using any code coverrage tool, it may indicate you how much of a pourcentage of your code have been covered (this is the case of PhpStorm code coverage). You can filter by files and check that the API call is fully coverred. Then your job is done !

Answer (score 0):

Have you select a Preferred Coverage engine (like xdebug or phpdbg) ?

If you're using phpstorm you can right click on test directory and then go to `Edit 'tests (PHPUnit)`.
[image]

Then select a code coverrage engine
[image]

Then click `Apply`.

Now run your test with code coverrage
[image]

Comment: Thanks Vincent ! that is helpful for testing

Comment: I know it's tempting but in general the comments section is not supposed to be used to say "thank you".
To do this, it is best to indicate that a post is positive by clicking on the buttons on the side of it.
I'm indicating this to you as you are a new user.
Anyway I'm glad to know that I could help you a little.